# RestKit: Inverse Relationship Empty After Initial Mapping

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, one-to-many, entity-relationship

Trying to connect two entities from my API from a single response.

```
{
    "id": 4546,
    "body": "Direct message",
    "status": "received",
    "from": {
      "id": 723,
      "signature": "Mr. Whatever"
    },
    "sent_at": "2014-06-05T21:33:15Z",
    "sent_to": ...
  }
```

The object is a `Message` entity, the `from` field is a nested `Sender` entity. Here is the relevant relationship mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping *senderMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Sender"
                                                          inManagedObjectStore:[AMModelManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];

    senderMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"remoteId" ];
    [senderMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                         @"id" : @"remoteId",
                                                         @"signature" : @"signature"
                                                         }];

    [messageMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"from"
                                                                                   toKeyPath:@"sender"
                                                                                 withMapping:senderMapping]];
```

The first time the objects are mapped, the relationship is not established. I see it being mapped in the log, but when I print any particular `Sender` object, its `messages` inverse relationship shows an empty array instead of a relationship fault.

```
Mapped relationship object from keyPath 'from' to 'sender'. Value: <Sender: 0x16a10990> (entity: Sender; id: 0x16a14580 <x-coredata:///Sender/t16539BDF-5606-442B-9EE2-D88363FB04AD29> ; data: {
    messages =     (
    );
    remoteId = 723;
    signature = "Mr. Whatever";
})
```

This makes the fetch requests I have in my application fail when I want to search for all messages from a given sender.

The next time I run the app and the mapping takes place again, all `Message` and `Sender` entities are remapped, the relationship is connected as expected, and my fetch requests behave as expected.

I really have no idea why the relationship isn't valid on the initial load. I don't know if it's a Core Data config issue or a RestKit issue, but it's driving me crazy and I would love any additional insight available. Glad to provide more information if necessary.

**Edit**

This is different than the proposed duplicate because this is a `to-one` relationship, so the proposed answer of using `RKAssignmentPolicyUnion` is inapplicable.

**Update**

Here is the fetch request I'm using for the controller I'm listening to:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Sender"];
    fetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(SELF.messages, $message, $message.direct == %@).@count > 0 && SELF.remoteId != %@", @(YES), user.remoteId];
    fetch.sortDescriptors = @[
                              [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"signature" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]
                              ];
```

Semantically I'm trying to say "Give me all the Senders that have sent a Message directly to the current user, and who are not the current user, sorted by their signature."

This fetch request fetches the Sender objects that I expect when I run it after my data is retrieved, but the controller fires no updates and my table remains empty until the next time I run the application.

Comment: Have you made the relationship ordered?

Comment: I have not. The "Ordered" checkbox for the to-many `Sender<->>Message`  is unchecked. Can you explain how that would affect this?

Comment: There are some bugs around ordered sets, just wondering if that could be a potential cause. Does the JSON contain multiple copies of the same item (one with nested content and one without)? I haven't seen your problem before so I'm just trying to think of potential reasons...

Comment: All of the `Message` JSON objects will contain a `Sender` object, and many of them will be the same `Sender`, yes. It should never be the case that there is a `Message` object with no `from` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K, another classic case of "You did it wrong and you were looking in all the wrong places to fix it."

I'd overridden the `didChangeValueForKey:` method on my `Message` entity's implementation to monitor some transient state, and neglected to call `[super didChangeValueForKey:key]`, which fubar'd the inverse connection assignments in the mapping. Absolutely no issue with Core Data or RestKit. Just me being careless.